# Multiple keyframes but doesn't seem to be running

Tags: javascript, css

I am doing a Vanilla JS and css practice and I am trying to run 2 keyframes in CSS on different elements but it doesn't seem to be working and I have no clue why.

Basically, when one clicks on the button, the classes 'applejuice; and 'pearjuice' are supposed to be added to the divs respectively and then the div with A will slide to the left and that with B will slide to the right. However, so far only the div with A is working, but not the B div.

Could anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance!!

```
**HTML:**
<body>
  <button onClick="opena()">press</button>
  <div class="pack">
    <div class="left" class="apple">A</div>
    <div class ="right"class="pear" >B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.pack{
  width:100%;

}
body{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}
.left{
  background:red;
  float:left;
  width:50vw;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;

}
.right{
  background:blue;
  width:50vw;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-left:0;
  margiin-right:0;
  float:right;

}
.applejuice{
  animation-name:gorda;
  animation-duration:2.0s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes gorda{
  0%{width:50vw;}
  100%{width:0vw;left: 50vw;}}
}
.pearjuice{
  animation-name:gordi;
  animation-duration:2.0s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes gordi{
  0%{width:50vw;}
  100%{width:0vw;right:0vw;}
}
```

JS:

```
function opena() {
  var eleme = document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0];
  var elemo = document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0];

  eleme.classList.add("applejuice");
  elemo.classList.add("pearjuice");
}
```

Comment: You have a double curly braces right at the end of `@keyframes gorda`, next time you post stuff like this put up a jsfiddle or something check the elements tab of the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put one extra } in gorda

```
@keyframes gorda{
  0%{width:50vw;}
  100%{width:0vw;left: 50vw;}
}
```

```js
function opena() {
  var eleme = document.getElementsByClassName("left")[0];
  var elemo = document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0];

  eleme.classList.add("applejuice");
  elemo.classList.add("pearjuice");
}
```

```css
.pack{
  width:100%;

}
body{
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}
.left{
  background:red;
  float:left;
  width:50vw;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;

}
.right{
  background:blue;
  width:50vw;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
  float:right;

}
.applejuice{
  animation-name:gorda;
  animation-duration:2.0s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes gorda{
  0%{width:50vw;}
  100%{width:0vw;left: 50vw;}
}
.pearjuice{
  animation-name:gordi;
  animation-duration:2.0s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes gordi{
  0%{width:50vw;}
  100%{width:0vw;right:0vw;}
}
```

```html
  <button onClick="opena()">press</button>
  <div class="pack">
    <div class="left" class="apple">A</div>
    <div class ="right"class="pear" >B</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you should vote to close the question instead of answering typo issue